Salesforce AppFlow creating objects in Amazon S3 without a specific content type
Today I have a flow configured within Amazon AppFlow, which fetches data from within Salesforce, extracts it as a CSV format, within the file format configuration, however, when saving within Amazon's S3 bucket, the file comes without the stipulated format , with the contenttype application/octet-stream, which should be like text/csv
The type of the saved object is also blank and I cannot edit the object within the bucket to change these values
I have the ACL disabled within the policy and I have already created permissions so that I can edit everything within the bucket, I am the owner of the bucket too but I cannot edit any object created by AppFlow
I have already carried out tests modifying the Amazon S3 policy to not allow ACL and to allow it, both did not work
I will post below my policies that I have today, which do not allow me to edit objects in the bucket that I created myself
{ "Version": "2008-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Sid": "AllowAppFlowDestinationActions", "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "Service": "appflow.amazonaws.com" }, "Action": "s3:PutObject", "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::salesforce", "arn:aws:s3:::salesforce/*" ] }, { "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::USERNUMBER:root" }, "Action": [ "s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectAcl" ], "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::salesforce", "arn:aws:s3:::salesforce/*", "arn:aws:s3:::salesforce/FOLDER/*" ] } ] }
